# EF 4.1 code first with Existing Database.Mapping Fks,table etc.Clarification needed

Tags: mapping, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I am learning code first and I have project to be used with an existing database.

I am a bit confused of what I meant to be doing.I will explain:

- Do I need to create an entityconfiguration for each table in my existing database?
- Within this EntityConfiguration for each table do I need to create foreign key relationships?
- Do I need to do a ToTable for each table in my existing database?
- Is there any free tool "codeplex" that pointing to an existing db will generate this codeFirst stuff?

I have seem few blogs about "EF Code first with existing db" but I am not sure or was not clear to me If Need to create this stuff or I will be getting strange errors like "MyColumn_MyColum" basically as if codeFirst is trying to build some FKs or something.

can somebody clarify?
thanks a lot. I know there are few questions but if you can answer 01 or 2 that would be fine.

thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the code to be generated for you use [database-first approach with DbContext API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-model-amp-database-first-walkthrough.aspx). Simply create EDMX file from your database and let DbContext Generator template generate all entities and context for you.

DbContext Fluent API is mainly targeted to the code-first development approach where EF will created database for you from the code you provided. It can be used with existing database but it requires much more skills and understanding of mapping wich EF can provide to you.

Generally:

- You don't need to provide `EntityConfiguration` for each table if you follow some naming conventions (entity name is singular form of table name, all properties have the same name, primary key in table and entity is named as Id or EntityNameId, etc.).
- You don't need to define relationships manually if you follow conventions with exposing navigation properties and possibly also foreign key properties. The issue can be naming of many-to-many keys and junction tables.
- `ToTable` is needed only if your entity does not follow naming convention or if you map some advance inheritance or splitting.

EF uses [a lot of default conventions](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetentityframework/thread/21c58114-db23-4be5-b810-b078e39d3a2e) which drive how the names should be defined. Conventions can be removed.

You will not do anything wrong if you define `EntityConfiguration` for each table - it will at least allow you learning what is needed and your mapping will be explicit / self documented.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply.I did a project using Edmx and I had lots of problems.We would like to use codefirst.Ideally we would start everything from scratch but for a particular project we already have a db ,and may be is not a bad thing as it will force us to understand a bit more how the mapping works! All our table have singular name.Yes I do have many junction tables and many to many,that is what is tricky.I will have a look at those conventions.Is there any sort of workaround where somehow I could generate relationship etc.. and then copy and paste them?Does edmx generate the same cod

Comment: Looked at those conventions but the msdn does not tell very much.Cannot see what the convention actually is.

Comment: DbContext Generator template doesn't generate the code first mapping. It still uses Edmx as source of mapping data. There is no workaround - or at least no official. Fluent API is about writing code not about generating code.

Comment: regarding conventions am i missing something or in the msdn you cannot actually see what they are.EG foreignkey should be "tablename_id" etc...

Comment: Yes that is possible. It was supposed to use as code first so documentation doesn't describe how to use it with existing database.